# Installing helm charts on kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am new to devops and facing one issue.

I am trying to install helm chart into kubernetes cluster and dont know how to do it.
Actually I know helm command to install but dont know how to install it on aws kubernetes cluster.

**Access Kubernetes cluster:**
I access Kubernetes cluster with below command:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=<path to config file> get pods -n dev
```

Now if I try to use helm chart with above command it errors out

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=<path to config file> helm list
```

**Error: unknown command "helm" for "kubectl"**

The error seems to be correct but I dont know how to access the kubernetes client via config file and running helm commands.

Answer (score 3):

Helm is a separate commandline tool. so just

```
helm list --kubeconfig <path to config file>
helm ls --kubeconfig <path to config file>
```

Btw. you can omit  generall if its located in ~/.kube/config for both kubectl and helm commands

Comment: helm list --kubeconfig <path>  - is returning list of my local cluster only, not of the kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 0):

Helm command is not part of `kubectl`. It's a separate tool you need to install. Please check the [Helm official doc installation](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/) page.

After the installation you should be able to execute:

```
$ helm list
```

Comment: I know that, but I need to perform the helm commands on the kubernetes cluster which I used to access via kubeconfig

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was wrong but solved it with helm2. earlier I had helm3